# c# code to copy files between two dates

Tags: c#-4.0, date, directory, copy

I need to copy all the files in a folder based on two dates.
Suppose if if service run, i need to copy all the files between today's date to diff of 5 days.

Am using below code, but it is copying files only on date-5 th day.
where i need all the files from date-5th day.Am using below code

```
DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(dlg.SelectedPath);
DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo(dlg2.SelectedPath);

var files = source.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(file => file.LastWriteTime.Date.Equals(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5));
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    File.Copy(file.FullName, target.FullName + "\\" + file.Name, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the files' LastWriteTime to the date as being exactly equal.

Try:

```
(file => file.LastWriteTime.Date >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5))
```

Comment: @WeylandYutani, perhaps - I read the question as "any file from five days ago until now".